# Increase Performance of DevEx WPF Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, devexpress

I'm using the DevEx DXGrid (WPF) to show about 2,000 rows of data.  I'm using a DataRow Template to get Master-Detail behavior (a new detail grid for each row).

My application responds extremely slow to almost all use input (to the grid).  for example:

- scrolling
- expand/collapse group rows
- resize app window

I've contacted DevEx support about this - but they say the solution is non trivial and they are waiting until next major version to 'fix' this.

Have you found any solutions to these problems?  I'm hoping there is a way to structure xaml or code to avoid some of the performance problems.  I'd be very interested to hear what performance problems you've encountered with the DXGrid and how you solved (or not) them.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, we have changed the way the DXGrid works and it should operate faster.  However, this improvement will be only visible in 10.2 and it relates the expanding / collapsing group rows.

If you have problems with scrolling, please post a sample project in the support center showing your performance issues.  We will try to improve the control based on your particular situation.

Comment: I had to suspend work on this part of my application for a while so I never got to test 10.2.  When I come back to it, I will.

Comment: We will be glad to know your results :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, simply put: the less controls, the faster it will be.

When using the GridControl, you may want to look into using the [CellDisplayTemplate](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.ColumnBase.CellDisplayTemplate) and use a very lightweight control to display the content of the cell, and then use the [CellEditTemplate](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.ColumnBase.CellEditTemplate) for your heavier edit control, as the CellEditTemplate is not is not loaded until the user enters the cell. This becomes very powerful the bigger your GridControl is.

See [3](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/17112/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/performance-improvement/optimized-mode) or [4](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/11142/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/performance-improvement) for more info on GridControl optimization.